# Animate Effect addClass/removeClass with jQuery UI

Tags: jquery-ui, animation, effect, addclass, removeclass

In order to add a fade transition to addClass/removeClass I am using jQuery UI:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('header nav a').hover(
        function(){
            $('header').stop().removeAttr("style").addClass('header-pink', 'slow')
        },
        function(){
            $('header').stop().removeClass('header-pink', 'slow')
        }
    )
});
```

My goal is: to change (with a fade animation/effect) the background-color of the parent element (header) when :hover the child element (hover nav a). The css class is very simple:

```
.header-pink { background: pink; }
```

The HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Of course, I am calling jQuery and jQuery UI with no errors:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"</script>
<script src="js/libs/jquery.effects.core.min.js"></script>
```

The jQuery script does not work properly because:

- The class is added (onmouseover) but with no transition (fade) effect.
- The class is added in a undesired way: `<header style="background:
  pink;">` I use `.removeAtrr("style")` to avoid this odd behavior.
- The class is not removed (onmouseout).

Using `.animate()` to animate colors with jQuery UI is something I prefer to avoid because I am using variables with [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and, of course, I want the style only to be modified by the stylesheet.

Please, [check my project to get an idea](http://dmg-01.net/test/). As you can see, my intention is to replace the background color of the fixed `<header>` with the color of the links when you place the cursor over the links. In other words, the background color of the `<header>` turns with a transitional fade animation/effect as blue or pink as soon as the pointer is :hover the link "Posts." or "Links." but it recovers its original state (with no css class, `.removeClass()`) as soon as the pointer is out with the same transitional fade animation/effect. Please note that my project is still in development and I am currently testing the effect with same properties for all the links; when I accomplish the desired result I will apply the individual properties (background-color) for every link.

Comment: By inspecting the source, I've realized that the "style" atributte is added (which I don't like it) and an odd behaviour is taking place: a large amount of dynamic rgb values are added in order to create a fade effect. It looks like very dirty! In addition, the "style" attribute remains empty after the transition.